# How do I combine array sections programmatically?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sections

How do I best to pass this back for x number of sections programmatically vs having to specify each section in the return statement? Is there a way to loop and combine these then return in a combined array for my UserSettings.Sections[x]?

My current return statement:

```
return [self.loadFAQs(), self.loadX(section: UserSettings.Sections[0]), self.loadX(section: UserSettings.Sections[1])]

class func getZendeskFAQs() -> [ZendeskFaqs] {

    // Clear storage
    clearDataFAQs()

    let count = loadArticles(labels: UserSettings.Sections)
    print("total articles loaded: ", count)

    // the number of self.loadX sections will vary... how do I do this and return?
    return [self.loadFAQs(), self.loadX(section: UserSettings.Sections[0]), self.loadX(section: UserSettings.Sections[1])]


}

// MARK - Private methods to load data
private class func loadFAQs() -> ZendeskFaqs {
    var faqs = [ZendeskFaq]()
    faqs.append(ZendeskFaq(titled: "faq 1.1"))
    faqs.append(ZendeskFaq(titled: "faq 1.2"))
    faqs.append(ZendeskFaq(titled: "faq 1.3"))
    return ZendeskFaqs(section: "Set 1", includeFAQs: faqs)
}
private class func loadX(section: String) -> ZendeskFaqs {
    var faqs = [ZendeskFaq]()

    var myIndex = 0

    while myIndex < articleData.count {
        if section == articleData[myIndex].label_name {
            faqs.append(ZendeskFaq(titled: articleData[myIndex].title))
        }
        myIndex = myIndex + 1
    }
    return ZendeskFaqs(section: section, includeFAQs: faqs)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want a single `Array` of type `[ZendeskFaq]`, or that you just want to create your return statement without hardcoding the function calls?

Comment: you can .flatmap to join nested arrays. You can return arrays like so 'func this() -> [that] {}'

Comment: You can do `[[self.loadFAQs], UserSettings.Sections.map({ loadX(section: $0) })].flatMap({ $0 })` which would give you just one array with all of the above in it.. but it is unclear what you actually want..

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to explain but basically I have three arrays (same array format) I am returning.  Each is a section so that they break out in a table view with sections.  The problem is that the number of loadX sections will vary "x" so at one time I may only have have LoadFAQs and 2 of the loadX.  Next time the app is run ( based on changes to the source data ) I may 5 or some other number of loadX sections.  I tried the flatmap but  that barfed with with a sigbart error:
    return [[self.loadFAQs], UserSettings.Sections.map({ loadX(section: $0) })].flatMap({ $0 }) as! [ZendeskFaqs]

Comment: Or I guess I could say how does one add data to a table with a varying number of sections each time they load the table?  I am reading the data in one pass to count those up.  Then reading the data again and loading to the right array for that section.  Add up the sections and then display in my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn to use the beautiful methods available in Swift for collections, like `map`, `filter` and `flatMap`. I suggest reading up about these, at the very least in the documentation available in Xcode.

Try this code:

```
class func getZendeskFAQs() -> [ZendeskFaqs] {

    // Clear storage
    clearDataFAQs()

    let count = loadArticles(labels: UserSettings.Sections)
    print("total articles loaded: ", count)

    return [self.loadFAQs()] + UserSettings.Sections.map { self.loadX(section: $0) }
}

// MARK - Private methods to load data
private class func loadFAQs() -> ZendeskFaqs {
    var faqs = [ZendeskFaq]()
    faqs.append(ZendeskFaq(titled: "faq 1.1"))
    faqs.append(ZendeskFaq(titled: "faq 1.2"))
    faqs.append(ZendeskFaq(titled: "faq 1.3"))
    return ZendeskFaqs(section: "Set 1", includeFAQs: faqs)
}

private class func loadX(section: String) -> ZendeskFaqs {
    let faqs = articleData
        .flatMap { article -> ZendeskFaq? in
            guard section == article.label_name else {
                return nil
            }
            return ZendeskFaq(titled: article.title)
        }

    return ZendeskFaqs(section: section, includeFAQs: faqs)
}
```

In order to get all of the elements in the array you can use the `map` function to convert it from one type into another. It's how you can get all of the sections mapped into your `ZendeskFaqs` objects, as you can see in my code sample.

You also don't need to use an index counter, like you had with `myIndex`, by the way. You can simply call something like:

```
for article in articleData {
   if section == article.label_name {
      ...
   }
}
```